# Adding Email Verification At Registration For Zend2 ZFCUser

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I have a working application of `Zend2` Skeleton with `ZFCUser` handling the registration and login system. I know from the docs that `ZFCUser` does not handle registration verification "As of yet". But I would like to integrate it.

I am new to MVC so I am trying to avoid sticking things places where they do not belong. I figure the best way to handle this would be to edit the mysql queries which create a new user by adding a hash for verification then create a custom function which creates a custom link then sends it in an email.

I have no problem writing this but I can not find how ZFCUser is creating the new users.

Where are these insert statements located? 
Is there a better way to handle this that is well documented online?

Thanks,

Comment: There's at least one module out there which already does what you want -> https://github.com/hrevert/HtUserRegistration Regardless of if you choose to use it (or fork it) it's probably a good place to start if you're looking for an example.

Comment: @Crisp thank you very much that worked like a charm. I do have one issue, I want to block users from logging in till they verify and in the github page it says you can do that as well as provides an adapter. Where do I add the adapter to make that work and do I need to change anything else in the application to make sure it works right? http://stackoverflow.com/q/35568928/2218253